# what is the security/verification system paypal IPN use called?

Tags: authentication, security, webhooks, paypal-ipn

In the implementation of an IPN listener:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNImplementation/

I understand the IPN listener verifies that the message sent to it comes from paypal by using these steps:

> Your listener sends the complete message back to PayPal using HTTPS
> POST.
>
> Prefix the returned message with the cmd=_notify-validate variable,
> but do not change the message fields, the order of the fields, or the
> character encoding from the original message.
>
> Send response messages back to PayPal
>
> PayPal sends one of the following words back to your listener:
>
> VERIFIED (if the message matches the original)
> INVALID (if the message does not match the original)

I am very interested in implementing this security feature in a webhook I want to develop but I can't find documentation on how this actually work on server side. what is this verification called?

I assume:
paypal saves a request's data in a database before posting it to the IPN listener.
When the listener post back the data to Paypal, the latter just checks it is in its database.
If it exists, return "VERIFIED" and it not return "INVALID"

Is it that simple?
Is it robust?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume: PayPal saves a request's data in a database before posting it to the IPN listener. When the listener post back the data to PayPal, the latter just checks it is in its database. If it exists, return "VERIFIED" and it not return "INVALID"

Yes, that is essentially how PayPal IPN postbacks work. Whether it checks the whole stored data or a stored signature/hash of the data is an implementation detail, either is sufficient for verification.

---

Current PayPal Webhooks [support cryptographic verification](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/#link-eventheadervalidation) without a postback, so perhaps you are interested in something more modern than the 20-year-old IPN design that always depends on postbacks to determine authenticity.

Comment: thx for the reply. I was thinking about using a message signature but it requires a shared key.

Comment: I can't find documentation on how to securely share a key between the client and provider. Using a simple form submission via https is enough?

Comment: is there a name for the method paypal IPN is using?

Comment: Only sharing a public cert is required to verify a signature, that is what PayPal Webhooks does. The only private piece of information is the Webhook ID of when the webhook is first set up

Comment: the webhook ID should remain secret I assume? if it gets exposed, anyone can create a signature? From what I understand, with the postback method of IPN, there's no shared key and each message is verified by paypal that it comes from it. I fail to understand how is message signature better.

Comment: verifying a signature does not require a postback.

Comment: if some value like the webhook ID is not secret then the cert needs to be trusted.

Comment: I understand that but I mean in terms of security, it seems to me that postback is more secured? in message signature, if the secret gets exposed, anyone can impersonate the server. with postback, it does not seem so or am I missing something?

Comment: the signature cannot be signed by someone who does not have the private end of the cert.

Comment: isn't the cert public and accessible by all?

Comment: I would recommend brushing up on public and private key cryptography

Comment: I mean in general message signature relies on a shared private key:
https://hookdeck.com/webhooks/guides/how-to-implement-sha256-webhook-signature-verification

if this key is somehow exposed, anyone can pretty much impersonate the webhook provider right?

Comment: No, signatures can be verified with just a public key. The point is to verify that the true originator signed the message. For this verification to be valid, the cert needs to come from a trusted source.

Comment: For an example of the PAYPAL-CERT-URL header that PayPal uses in its own webhooks: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-aecacc47 , you can view its contents with `openssl x509 -in filenamegoeshere -text`

Comment: The key thing is, either the cert itself (e.g. the URL to download it from) or part of the message being signed (e.g. the Webhook ID) needs to be known and trusted. Otherwise, anyone can provide their own cert and sign whatever message with it.

Comment: ok thx man for all the explanations